# MomentJs subtract time to actual

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to subtract actual time from a time variable (formatted in hh:mm:ss) and obtain the result in seconds, for example:

```
var time1 = "13:40:00";
var time1 = moment(time1, "HH:mm:ss");
var timeNow = ?
var time2 = time1 - timeNow  // expressed in s
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your needs fully but give this a try

```
var time1 = "13:40:00";
var time1 = moment(time1, "hh:mm:ss");
var time2 = time1.diff(moment(), 'seconds')
```

Comment: No, i have, as i wrote, a var like "var time1 = "13:40:00";" and i'd like to subtract actual time from that var..

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to get the difference between two moment objects. In your case:

```js
var time1 = '13:40:00';
var diff = moment().diff(moment(time1, 'HH:mm:ss'), 'seconds');
console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var time1 = moment.duration("24:40:00", "HH:mm:ss").asSeconds();
var timeNow =moment.duration(moment().format('HH:mm:ss'),"HH:mm:ss").asSeconds();
var log = time1-timeNow;
```